# Boostrap table only top border

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a bootstrap table (data-card type) to display a ranking.

I want to hide all borders of my table except the top one.

Actually, I can hide bottom of table with this code:

```css
#table1 {
    border-bottom:0 px;
}
```

but for example,border-right:0 px; or even left doesnt work. Could you help me please? Thanks

Comment: #table1{border: 0px; border-top:1px solid black;} Is it what you are looking for ?

Answer (score 0):

Override the td element styles

```
#table1 td {
    border-left:0;
    border-right:0;
    border-bottom:0;
}
```